# Javascript angular : Block response for http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a serious problem with my application, i use AngularJs.
I use "for" to go all over my ressource. for each ressource i do $http.get for have data about this ressource.
My problem is that my program dont wait to get response of $http.get and then $http.get() are apply for my last ressource.

I see all alert for my ressource in first and then alert('new user') for finish.

Thank's ;)

```
$scope.loadPlanning = function() {
        //var tasksRessource = [];
        //tasksRessource.push({name: 'Go-liiive', color: '#93C47D', from: new Date(2013, 10, 23, 1, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 25, 24, 0, 0)});
        //tasksRessource.push({name: 'Go-live', color: '#93C47D', from: new Date(2013, 10, 27, 1, 0, 0), to: new Date(2013, 10, 29, 24, 0, 0)});
        var data = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.ressources.length; i++) {

            var nameR = $scope.ressources[i].firstName + ' ' + $scope.ressources[i].lastName;
            alert(nameR);
            // On récupère la liste des visites clients associé a cet utilisateur
            //Visiteclient.getByRessource({id: $scope.ressources[i].id}, function(result) {
            $http.get("api/api/visiteclientsbyressource/" + $scope.ressources[i].id).success(function(result) {
                var tasksRessource = [];
                $scope.visiteclietest = result;

                for (var p = 0; p < $scope.visiteclietest.length; p++) {
                    var name = result[p].name;
                    var dateDebu = result[p].date;
                    var dateFin = result[p].date;
                    tasksRessource.push({name: name, color: '#93C47D', from: new Date(dateDebu), to: new Date(dateFin)});
                }

                $scope.pushData(tasksRessource);
            });

            $scope.pushData = function(taskr) {
                alert ('new user');     
                data.push({name: nameR,classes: "custom-row", tasks : taskr}); 
                console.log({name: nameR,classes: "custom-row", tasks : taskr});
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: There are several issues with your code, but I didn't really understand your problem or find a serious problem. What do you expect as the result and how do you check it?

Answer (score 0):

As AJAX calls are async you should use promises. Angular implements that pattern using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Here is a detailed [tutorial](http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/) using promises as a directive within Angular